# Material-UI date pickers' Icons are not visible

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]I am using material-ui for Datepicker component `import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";` date picker icons are not showing.

Please find codesandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7vzo5.

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem, can you be more specific ?

Comment: @sebastienbarbier Thanks ,have added screenshot along with problem please have a look.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you import 2 different components, `KeyboardDatePicker` and `DatePicker`

```
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  DatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
...
<KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
        <DatePicker
          keyboard
          InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
```

`KeyboardDatePicker` has icon. `DatePicker` has no icon. So you need to change `DatePicker` to `KeyboardDatePicker`

```
 <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
        />
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          keyboard
          InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans but in old version { import { DatePicker } from 'material-ui-pickers'; }  just adding keyboard props it's was working fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-pickers-playground-dctkg . BTW thanks.

Comment: @chhitijsrivastava DatePicker no longer has a `keyboard` prop. Using `KeyboardDatePicker` appears to be the way to get that functionality with the current version.